# How can I get top ten alternatively?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  pr1.id AS user_id,
  pr1.title AS user_name,
  pr2.id AS liker_id,
  pr2.title AS liker_name,
  x.which AS which_table,
  x.cnt AS total,
  x.rank AS rk
FROM 
(
  SELECT rid, rootid, which, COUNT(*) AS cnt, rank
  FROM
  (
    SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 3 rank, rid, rootid, 'vote' which
    FROM p_likes, (select @rank1 := -2) q
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 3 rank, rid, rootid, 'comment' which
    FROM p_comments, (select @rank2 := -1) q
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT @rank3 := @rank3 + 3 rank, rid, rootid, 'friend' which
    FROM relations, (select @rank3 := 0) q
  ) y
  WHERE y.rootid = 1246 AND y.rootid <> y.rid
  GROUP BY y.rid, y.rootid, y.which
) x
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr1 on x.rootid = pr1.id
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr2 on x.rid = pr2.id
ORDER BY x.rank desc, x.cnt desc, x.which
LIMIT 30;
```

My question is about the *ordering*. I want to get 10 rows *(if exist)* form each table. There is 3 tables *(`p_likes`, `p_comments`, `relations`)*. So the result should be 30 rows in maximum.

But what's my question: I need to make a order alternatively. I mean first row should be from `p_likes`, second one should be from `p_comments`, third one should be from `relations`, fourth one should be from `p_likes` and so on ..

I also want to sort them based on the `cnt` column first. I mean, I want top ten of each table.

How can I do that?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Isn't my question clear for you?

Comment: Refer to the accepted answer linked

Comment: @stack can you tried my ans ?

Comment: You want to base your query on only 10 p_likes, 10 p_comments, and 10 relations? All records picked randomly; no matter what rid or rootid? Or all records matching rootid = 1246? And if a table only contains 1 record then we work on 21 records instead of 30?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes I want to base my query on only 10 `p_likes`, 10 `p_comments`, and 10 `relations` (if there is 10 row matched for each of them). Those 10 rows isn't randomly, they are the ones which have bigger `cnt`.

Answer (score 1):

you should add number as you want to get order and give first order by it like below as **num**

```
SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 3 rank, rid, rootid, 'vote',1 as num which
FROM p_likes, (select @rank1 := -2) q group by y.rid, y.rootid limit 1,10
UNION ALL 
SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 3 rank, rid, rootid, 'comment',2 as num which
FROM p_comments, (select @rank2 := -1) q y.rid, y.rootid limit 1,10
UNION ALL 
SELECT @rank3 := @rank3 + 3 rank, rid, rootid, 'friend',3 as num which
FROM relations, (select @rank3 := 0) q  y.rid, y.rootid limit 1,10
```

Comment: Your query isn't what I'm looking for, thank you anyway. I guess my question isn't clear enough

Comment: @stack do you need 10 row per table ?

Comment: yes. 10 rows per table, and 10 rows should be the ones have biggest `cnt`

Comment: @stack I have change my ans. but do not understand biggest cnt ? can you give example ?

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. I'll ask another question contains more explanations

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by `rid, rootid, which`. You select `rid, rootid, which, COUNT(*) AS cnt, rank`. So you get *the* `rid`, *the* `rootid`, *the* `which` and the count of records per `rid, rootid, which`. But which of all the ranks per `rid, rootid, which` do you think you get? If there are ranks 3, 6, 9 for the `rid, rootid, which`, which do you think the DBMS will pick? You don't tell it (which you would be able to do with `MIN` or `MAX`), so the DBMS picks a rank arbitrarily. You see, your approach cannot work.

In the comments section you say you want the 10 records per table with the highest count (per `rid` for `rootid` 1246 obviously). So you must apply `rootid = 1246 and rootid <> rid` for each table and count directly. Then use `LIMIT` to only take up to ten records per table.

```
SELECT
  pr1.id AS user_id,
  pr1.title AS user_name,
  pr2.id AS liker_id,
  pr2.title AS liker_name,
  x.which AS which_table,
  x.cnt AS total
FROM 
(
  (
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'vote' AS which, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM p_likes
    WHERE rootid = 1246 and rootid <> rid
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 10
  )
  union all 
  (
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'comment' AS which, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM p_comments
    WHERE rootid = 1246 and rootid <> rid
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 10
  )
  union all 
  (
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'friend' AS which, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM relations
    WHERE rootid = 1246 and rootid <> rid
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 10
  )
) x
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr1 ON x.rootid = pr1.id
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr2 ON x.rid = pr2.id
ORDER BY x.cnt DESC, x.which;
```

Comment: Than you .. but your query returns just 3 rows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL1xH.png

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974970/how-can-i-order-selected-rows-alternatively). it is my same question by explaining the other way.

Comment: So there are rows missing? Does user 1246 have more friends or more commenters or more likers that don't appear in the results?

Comment: the problem is {I don't know English and I cannot explain what I want exactly} ..! thank you anyway. Upvote for your attempt