# How can I order selected rows alternatively

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  pr1.id AS user_id,
  pr1.title AS user_name,
  pr2.id AS liker_id,
  pr2.title AS liker_name,
  x.which AS which_table,
  x.cnt AS total
FROM 
(
  SELECT rid, rootid, which, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM
  (
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'vote' which FROM p_likes
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'comment' which FROM p_comments
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'friend' which FROM relations
  ) y
  WHERE y.rootid = 1246 AND y.rootid <> y.rid
  GROUP BY y.rid, y.rootid, y.which
) x
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr1 on x.rootid = pr1.id
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr2 on x.rid = pr2.id
ORDER BY x.cnt desc;
```

And here is the **output** of query above: *(`//` means the value of that record isn't related to this question.)*

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| user_id | user_name | liker_id | liker_name | which_table | total |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 7     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 5     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 3     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 3     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 2     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 2     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 2     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | friend      | 1     |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

All I'm trying to do is sorting rows alternatively. As you see, currently I order the results based on `total` column. While I need to sort them both based on `total` and `which_table` alternatively. Something like this: *(expected output)*

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| user_id | user_name | liker_id | liker_name | which_table | total |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 7     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 3     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | friend      | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 5     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 2     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 3     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 2     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 2     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | comment     | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 1     |
| //      | //        | //       | //         | vote        | 1     |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: really this output do you want ?  because I can not see any order here

Comment: @krishnpatel You don't see any order?? That's pretty much obvious. I want to sort the result based on `which_table` *(alternatively)* and `total`.

Comment: up vote. I under stand your question. it is really hard to do this order.

Comment: @krishnpatel I'm glad you understand it and thank you for the upvote. I guess I need to use *variables* for doing that. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972905/how-can-i-get-top-ten-alternatively)

Comment: I think you need different thing. first get max total of three different table and make appear  first than second hight total come and different table name. am I right ?

Comment: @krishnpatel if I get you right, yes.

Comment: The logic seems simple - for each rid, rootid block of whichs feed the total for the vote which to the other whichs (in a separate column) and then sort descending on that column then which.

Comment: This is not easily solved. In order to determine in which position to place a row, one must look at the complete result set and iterate through it. This could be done with a recursive query, but MySQL doesn't support that. It could also be done with a stored procedure, but MySQL's language may be too limited for this; I am not sure. So your best bet may be to do this outside the DBMS. Write an app; select the data; run through your result array again and again to determine the position of each row.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ah ok thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below query. Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY ..)` generate a rank/record number for each `'which'` items and sort based on this . (Hope this will work for you, i don't have the table schema or sample data  script to try myself)

```
SELECT
  pr1.id AS user_id,
  pr1.title AS user_name,
  pr2.id AS liker_id,
  pr2.title AS liker_name,
  x.which AS which_table,
  x.cnt AS total
FROM 
(
  SELECT rid, rootid, which, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY which ORDER BY rid) AS new_order
  FROM
  (
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'vote' which FROM p_likes
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'comment' which FROM p_comments
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'friend' which FROM relations
  ) y
  WHERE y.rootid = 1246 AND y.rootid <> y.rid
  GROUP BY y.rid, y.rootid, y.which
) x
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr1 on x.rootid = pr1.id
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr2 on x.rid = pr2.id
ORDER BY new_order,x.cnt desc;
```

Comment: @stack Sorry, this query for Sql-Server only. Please try the MySQL equal-ant function for ROW_NUMBER here..

Comment: Yes, MySQL lacking analytic functions makes this very complicated. But the approach is good and may be mimicked with variables in MySQL somehow. It should be `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY which ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)` and `ORDER BY new_order, FIELD(which,'vote', 'comment', 'friend');`, though. (Resp. `CASE which WHEN 'vote' THEN 1 WHEN 'comment' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END` instead of `FIELD(which,'vote', 'comment', 'friend')` for standard SQL).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is all that difficult - my model below doesn't differ in principal from the question and I use correlated sub queries to allocate the vote (in my model live) total for all whichs for an id

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from onetime_contest;
+------+-----------+------------+
| id   | status    | valid_till |
+------+-----------+------------+
|    1 | live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | waiting   | 2017-01-01 |
|    3 | completed | 2017-01-01 |
|    4 | Waiting   | 2017-01-01 |
|    5 | live      | 2017-06-01 |
|    6 | waiting   | 2017-06-01 |
|    7 | completed | 2017-06-01 |
|    8 | Waiting   | 2017-06-01 |
|    1 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    3 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    3 | Waitng    | 2017-01-01 |
|    4 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    6 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    7 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    8 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    1 | Waiting   | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Waiting   | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Waiting   | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 | Live      | 2017-01-01 |
+------+-----------+------------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from
    -> (
    -> select id, status ,count(*) as t1 ,count(*) as t2 from onetime_contest o1 where status = 'Live' group by id,status
    -> union
    -> select id, status ,count(*) as t1 ,(select count(*) from onetime_contest o2 where status = 'Live' and o2.id = o1.id  group by o2.id,o2.status)
    ->   from onetime_contest o1 where status = 'Waiting' group by id,status
    -> union
    -> select id, status ,count(*) as t1 ,(select count(*) from onetime_contest o2 where status = 'Live' and o2.id = o1.id  group by o2.id,o2.status)
    ->  from onetime_contest o1 where status = 'Completed' group by id,status
    -> ) s
    -> order by s.t2 desc,s.id,
    -> case when s.status = 'Live' then 1
    ->  when s.status = 'Waiting' then 2
    -> else 3 end;
+------+-----------+----+------+
| id   | status    | t1 | t2   |
+------+-----------+----+------+
|    2 | Live      |  4 |    4 |
|    2 | waiting   |  3 |    4 |
|    1 | live      |  2 |    2 |
|    1 | Waiting   |  1 |    2 |
|    3 | Live      |  1 |    1 |
|    3 | completed |  1 |    1 |
|    4 | Live      |  1 |    1 |
|    4 | Waiting   |  1 |    1 |
|    5 | live      |  1 |    1 |
|    6 | Live      |  1 |    1 |
|    6 | waiting   |  1 |    1 |
|    7 | Live      |  1 |    1 |
|    7 | completed |  1 |    1 |
|    8 | Live      |  1 |    1 |
|    8 | Waiting   |  1 |    1 |
+------+-----------+----+------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand well your question, you can use:

SELECT `SELECT
  pr1.id AS user_id,
  pr1.title AS user_name,
  pr2.id AS liker_id,
  pr2.title AS liker_name,
  x.which AS which_table,
  x.cnt AS total,
FROM 
(
  SELECT rid, rootid, which, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM
  (
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'vote' which FROM p_likes
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'comment' which FROM p_comments
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT rid, rootid, 'friend' which FROM relations
  ) y
  WHERE y.rootid = 1246 AND y.rootid <> y.rid
  GROUP BY y.rid, y.rootid, y.which
) x
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr1 on x.rootid = pr1.id
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr2 on x.rid = pr2.id
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6;`

These numbers represent your columns. So, if you want to sort them based on total and which_table, you can write:  SELECT(your code) order by 5,6

Comment: You've obviously misunderstood what the OP wants. The rows shall be ordered by `which_table` alternatingly: vote-comment-friend-vote-comment-friend-... as long as possible. Additionally the data shall be ordered by count (i.e. vote with highest count first, then comment with highest count, then friend with highest count, then vote with second-highest count, etc.